# Add 3 variable to an empty DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to append 3 variables to an empty dataframe after each loop.

```
dfvol = dfvol.append([stock,mean,median],columns=['Stock','Mean','Median'])
```

Columns in Dataframe should be ['Stock','Median','Mean']

Result should be:

[image]

How can I solve the problem, because something with the append code is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `append` method doesn't work like that. You would only use the `columns` parameter if you were creating a `DataFrame` object. You either want to create a *second* temporary DataFrame and append it to the main DataFrame like this:

```
df_tmp = pd.DataFrame([[stock,mean,median]], columns=['Stock','Mean','Median'])
dfvol = dfvol.append(df_tmp)
```

...or you can use a dictionary like this:

```
dfvol = dfvol.append({'Stock':stock,'Mean':mean,'Median':median}, ignore_index=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to use a syntax for creating a new dataframe to append to it, which is not going to work.

Here is one way you can try to do what you want

```
df.loc[len(df)] = [stock,mean,median]
```

The better approach will be creating list of entries and when your loop is done to create the dataframe using that list (instead of appending to df with every iteration)
Like this:

```
some_list = []
for a in b:
  some_list.append([stock,mean,median])

df = pd.DataFrame(some_list, columns = ['Stock','Mean','Median'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
In [256]: dfvol = pd.DataFrame()

In [257]: stock = ['AAPL', 'FB']

In [258]: mean = [600.356, 700.245]

In [259]: median = [281.788, 344.55]

In [265]: dfvol = dfvol.append(pd.DataFrame(zip(stock, mean, median), columns=['Stock','Mean','Median']))

In [265]: dfvol
Out[265]: 
  Stock     Mean   Median
0  AAPL  600.356  281.788
1    FB  700.245  344.550
```

Answer (score 0):

check the append notation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.append.html). There are multiple way to do it.

```py
dfvol = dfvol.append(pd.DataFrame([[Stock,Mean,Median]],columns=['Stock','Mean','Median']))
```

Comment: Not sure what will this exactly do the way you put it there :-) I get the idea, but the syntax is wrong.

Comment: If I am using your suggestion, the value is a string 'Stock' or 'Mean' or 'Median'. I would like to pass a variable (stock) or (mean) or (median). Example variable stock is 'FB'. Mean is 355.66 and Median is 777.567.